# how to escape the space in Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles C#

Tags: c#, escaping, xcopy

i am trying to escape sequence the C:\Program Files space.
Originally i escaped it within a string

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("XCOPY.EXE", "/E /I /Y \"" + ProgramFiles + "\\WinCon2\\*.*\" \"" + pfadauswahl + "\\Backup\\" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "\\WinCon2\\\"");
```

Since i try to upgrade my program a bit to get rid of endless string chains,
the new version looks like:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("XCOPY.EXE", "/E /I /Y " + pathWinCon2 + " " + backupPathWinCon2);
```

While in my first attempt the Program Files was escaped by hand

```
\"" + ProgramFiles + "\\WinCon2\\*.*\" \""
```

and the "C:\Program Files" in a string...

Now i wanted to use either

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
```

or

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROGRAMFILES")
```

but how can i escape them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you want?

You can specify the path in quotes..

Since space separates different arguments, you have to give those paths in quotes.

```
pathWinCon2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + @"\WinCon2\*.*\";

backupPathWinCon2 = pfadauswahl + @"\Backup\" + dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + @"\WinCon2\";

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("XCOPY.EXE", "/E /I /Y \"" + pathWinCon2 + "\" \"" + backupPathWinCon2 + "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with this and it works as expected:

```
string s = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
string q = "Microsoft Sql Server";
string path = Path.Combine(s, q);
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.EXE";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/K DIR \"" + path + "\" /D /S";
p.Start();
```